# In Email, Image (img) Source (src) Tags are rewritten as relative links. How to fix?

Tags: tinymce, href, image, src, html-email

I'm working on sending out an html based email, and every time it sends the image src tags and some of the anchor href tags are modified to be relative url's.

**Update 2:** This is happening between when the body of the email is generated and sent and when it arrives in my inbox.

**Update:** I am using Postfix on a LAMPP server. In addition, I am using Zend_Mail to send the emails out.

For example, I have a link:

```
src="http://www.furnituretrainingcompany.com/images/email/highpoint_2009_04/header.jpg"
```

And it gets rewritten as:

```
src="../../../../images/email/highpoint_2009_04/header.jpg"
```

What can cause this to occur and how is it corrected?

Email headers:

```
Return-Path: <root@example.com>
X-Original-To: gabe@example.com
Delivered-To: gabe@example.com
Received: by mail.example.com (Postfix, from userid 0)
     id 6BF012252; Tue, 14 Apr 2009 12:15:20 -0600 (MDT)
To: Gabriel <gabe@example.com>
Subject: Free Map to Sales Success
From: Somebody <info@example.com>
Date: Tue, 14 Apr 2009 12:15:20 -0600
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: multipart/related
Content-Disposition: inline
Message-Id: <20090414181520.6BF012252@mail.example.com>
```

Original content to be sent out:

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <a href="http://www.furnituretrainingcompany.com">
            <img moz-do-not-send="true" alt="The Furniture Training Company - Know More. Sell More." src="http://www.furnituretrainingcompany.com/images/email/highpoint_2009_04/header.jpg" border="0" height="123" width="600">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
 width="600">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top"><img alt="Visit us at High Point to receive your free training poster" src="http://www.furnituretrainingcompany.com/images/email/highpoint_2009_04/hero.jpg" moz-do-not-send="true" height="150" width="600"><br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
 width="600">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="top"><img alt="" src="http://www.furnituretrainingcompany.com/images/email/highpoint_2009_04/spacer_content_left.jpg" moz-do-not-send="true" height="30" width="30"><br>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="top"><font originaltag="yes" style="font-size: 9px; font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;" color="#000000" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><big><big><big><big><small><big><b>See you at Market</b></big><br>
      </small></big></big></big></big></font>
      <font originaltag="yes" style="font-size: 9px; font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;" color="#000000" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><big><big><big><big><small><br>
      </small></big></big></big></big></font><small><font
 face="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">Visit our space to get your free
Map to Sales Success poster! This unique 24 X 36 color poster is your
guide to developing high volume salespeople with larger tickets. Find
us in the new NHFA Retailer Resource Center located in the Plaza. <br>
      <br>
Don&#8217;t miss Mark Lacy&#8217;s entertaining seminar "Help Wanted! My Sales
Associates Can&#8217;t Sell Water to a Thirsty Camel." He&#8217;ll reveal powerful
secrets for turning sales associates into furniture experts that will
sell. See him Saturday, April 25th at 11:30 AM in the seminar room of
the
new NHFA Retail Resource Center in the Plaza. <br>
      <br>
Stop by our space to learn how our ingenious internet-delivered
training courses are easy to use, guaranteed to work, and cheaper than
the daily donuts. Over 95% report increased sales. <br>
      <br>
Plan to see us at High Point. </font></small> 
<font originaltag="yes" style="font-size: 9px; font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;" color="#000000" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><big><big><big><big><small><small><br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      </small></small></big></big></big></big></font><small><font
 originaltag="yes"
 style="font-size: 9px; font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"
 color="#000000" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><big><big><big><small>
      </small></big></big></big></font></small>
<a href="http://www.furnituretrainingcompany.com/map"><img alt="Find out more" src="http://www.furnituretrainingcompany.com/images/email/highpoint_2009_04/image_content_left.jpg" moz-do-not-send="true" border="0" height="67" width="326"></a><br>
      <br>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="top">
        <img alt="" src="http://www.furnituretrainingcompany.com/images/email/highpoint_2009_04/spacer_content_middle.jpg" moz-do-not-send="true" height="28" width="28"><br>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="top"><img alt="Roadmap to Sales Success poster" src="http://www.furnituretrainingcompany.com/images/email/highpoint_2009_04/image_content_right.jpg" moz-do-not-send="true" height="267" width="186"><br>
      <font face="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"><small><font originaltag="yes" style="font-size: 9px; font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;" color="#000000" size="1"><big><big><big><small><b>Road
Map to Sales Success<br>
      </b><br>
      </small></big></big></big></font>This beautiful poster is yours
free for simply stopping by and visiting with us at High Point. <span
 class="moz-txt-slash">Our space is located inside the </span>new NHFA
Retailer Resource Center in the Plaza Suites, 222 South Main St, 1st
Floor. We will be at market from Sat April 25th until Thur
April 30th. </small></font><br>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="top"><img alt="" src="http://www.furnituretrainingcompany.com/images/email/highpoint_2009_04/spacer_content_right.jpg"
 moz-do-not-send="true" height="30" width="30"><br>
      <br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
 width="600">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="top"><img alt="" src="http://www.furnituretrainingcompany.com/images/email/highpoint_2009_04/disclaimer_divider.jpg"
 moz-do-not-send="true" height="25" width="600"><br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
 width="600">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="top"><img alt="" src="http://www.furnituretrainingcompany.com/images/email/highpoint_2009_04/spacer_disclaimer_left.jpg"
 moz-do-not-send="true"></td>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="top"><img alt="" src="http://www.furnituretrainingcompany.com/images/email/highpoint_2009_04/spacer_disclaimer_middle.jpg"
 moz-do-not-send="true"><br>
      <font originaltag="yes"
 style="font-size: 9px; font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"
 color="#666666" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><big><big><big><big><small><small><small>If
you are not attending the High Point market in April but
would still like to receive a free Road Map to Sales Success poster
visit us on the web at <u><a moz-do-not-send="true"
 class="moz-txt-link-abbreviated"
 href="http://www.furnituretrainingcompany.com">www.furnituretrainingcompany.com</a></u>,
or to
speak with a Furniture Training Company representative, call toll free
(866) 755-5996. We do not offer free shipping outside of the U.S. and
Canada. Retailers outside of the U.S. and Canada may call for more
information. Limit one free Road Map to Sales Success per company.
Other copies of the poster may be purchased on our web site.<br>
      <br>
      </small></small></small></big></big></big></big></font> <font
 color="#666666"><small><font originaltag="yes"
 style="font-size: 9px; font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"
 face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><big><big><big><small><small>We
hope you found this message to be useful. However, if you'd
rather not receive future emails of this sort from The Furniture
Training Company, please <a moz-do-not-send="true"
 href="http://www.furnituretraining.com/contact">click here to
unsubscribe</a>.<br>
      <br>
      </small></small></big></big></big></font></small><small><font
 originaltag="yes"
 style="font-size: 9px; font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"
 face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><big><big><big><small><small>&copy;Copyright
2009 The Furniture Training Company.<br>
1770 North Research Park
Way, <br>
North Logan, UT 84341. <br>
All Rights Reserved.</small></small></big></big></big></font></small></font><br>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="top"><img alt=""
 src="http://www.furnituretrainingcompany.com/images/email/highpoint_2009_04/spacer_disclaimer_right.jpg"
 moz-do-not-send="true"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
 width="600">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="top"><img alt=""
 src="http://www.furnituretrainingcompany.com/images/email/highpoint_2009_04/footer.jpg"
 moz-do-not-send="true"> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
```

Content that gets sent:

```
<table border=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" width=3D"600" al=
ign=3D"center">=0D=0A<tbody>=0D=0A<tr>=0D=0A<td valign=3D"top"><a href=
=3D"http://www.furnituretrainingcompany.com"> <img src=3D"http://www.fur=
nituretrainingcompany.com/images/email/highpoint_2009_04/header.jpg" bor=
der=3D"0" alt=3D"The Furniture Training Company - Know More. Sell More."=
 width=3D"600" height=3D"123" /> </a></td>=0D=0A</tr>=0D=0A</tbody>=0D=
=0A</table>=0D=0A<table border=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0"=
 width=3D"600" align=3D"center">=0D=0A<tbody>=0D=0A<tr>=0D=0A<td valign=
=3D"top"><img src=3D"http://www.furnituretrainingcompany.com/images/emai=
l/highpoint_2009_04/hero.jpg" alt=3D"Visit us at High Point to receive y=
our free training poster" width=3D"600" height=3D"150" /><br /></td>=0D=
=0A</tr>=0D=0A</tbody>=0D=0A</table>=0D=0A<table border=3D"0" cellspacin=
g=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" width=3D"600" align=3D"center">=0D=0A<tbody>=
=0D=0A<tr>=0D=0A<td valign=3D"top" bgcolor=3D"#ffffff"><img src=3D"http:=
//www.furnituretrainingcompany.com/images/email/highpoint_2009_04/spacer=
_content_left.jpg" alt=3D"" width=3D"30" height=3D"30" /><br /></td>=0D=
=0A<td valign=3D"top" bgcolor=3D"#ffffff"><span style=3D"font-size: xx-s=
mall; font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #000000;">=

<big><big><big><big><small><big><strong>See you at Market</strong></big>=
<br /> </small></big></big></big></big></span> <span style=3D"font-size:=
 xx-small; font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #0000=
00;"><big><big><big><big><small><br /> </small></big></big></big></big><=
/span><small><span style=3D"font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">Vi=
sit our space to get your free Map to Sales Success poster! This unique=
 24 X 36 color poster is your guide to developing high volume salespeopl=
e with larger tickets. Find us in the new NHFA Retailer Resource Center=
 located in the Plaza. <br /> <br /> Don&rsquo;t miss Mark Lacy&rsquo;s=
 entertaining seminar "Help Wanted! My Sales Associates Can&rsquo;t Sell=
 Water to a Thirsty Camel." He&rsquo;ll reveal powerful secrets for turn=
ing sales associates into furniture experts that will sell. See him Satu=
rday, April 25th at 11:30 AM in the seminar room of the new NHFA Retail=
 Resource Center in the Plaza. <br /> <br /> Stop by our space to learn=
 how our ingenious internet-delivered training courses are easy to use,=
 guaranteed to work, and cheaper than the daily donuts. Over 95% report=
 increased sales. <br /> <br /> Plan to see us at High Point. </span></s=
mall> <span style=3D"font-size: xx-small; font-family: Verdana,Arial,Hel=
vetica,sans-serif; color: #000000;"><big><big><big><big><small><small><b=
r /> <br /> <br /> <br /> </small></small></big></big></big></big></span=
><small><span style=3D"font-size: xx-small; font-family: Verdana,Arial,H=
elvetica,sans-serif; color: #000000;"><big><big><big><small> </small></b=
ig></big></big></span></small> <a href=3D"http://www.furnituretrainingco=
mpany.com/map"><img src=3D"http://www.furnituretrainingcompany.com/image=
s/email/highpoint_2009_04/image_content_left.jpg" border=3D"0" alt=3D"Fi=
nd out more" width=3D"326" height=3D"67" /></a><br /> <br /></td>=0D=0A<=
td valign=3D"top" bgcolor=3D"#ffffff"><img src=3D"http://www.furnituretr=
ainingcompany.com/images/email/highpoint_2009_04/spacer_content_middle.j=
pg" alt=3D"" width=3D"28" height=3D"28" /><br /></td>=0D=0A<td valign=3D=
"top" bgcolor=3D"#ffffff"><img src=3D"http://www.furnituretrainingcompan=
y.com/images/email/highpoint_2009_04/image_content_right.jpg" alt=3D"Roa=
dmap to Sales Success poster" width=3D"186" height=3D"267" /><br /> <spa=
n style=3D"font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"><small><span style=
=3D"font-size: xx-small; color: #000000;"><big><big><big><small><strong>=
Road Map to Sales Success<br /> </strong><br /> </small></big></big></bi=
g></span>This beautiful poster is yours free for simply stopping by and=
 visiting with us at High Point. <span class=3D"moz-txt-slash">Our space=
 is located inside the </span>new NHFA Retailer Resource Center in the P=
laza Suites, 222 South Main St, 1st Floor. We will be at market from Sat=
 April 25th until Thur April 30th. </small></span><br /></td>=0D=0A<td v=
align=3D"top" bgcolor=3D"#ffffff"><img src=3D"http://www.furnituretraini=
ngcompany.com/images/email/highpoint_2009_04/spacer_content_right.jpg" a=
lt=3D"" width=3D"30" height=3D"30" /><br /> <br /></td>=0D=0A</tr>=0D=0A=

</tbody>=0D=0A</table>=0D=0A<table border=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpa=
dding=3D"0" width=3D"600" align=3D"center">=0D=0A<tbody>=0D=0A<tr>=0D=0A=
<td valign=3D"top" bgcolor=3D"#ffffff"><img src=3D"http://www.furnituret=
rainingcompany.com/images/email/highpoint_2009_04/disclaimer_divider.jpg=
" alt=3D"" width=3D"600" height=3D"25" /><br /></td>=0D=0A</tr>=0D=0A</t=
body>=0D=0A</table>=0D=0A<table border=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpaddi=
ng=3D"0" width=3D"600" align=3D"center">=0D=0A<tbody>=0D=0A<tr>=0D=0A<td=
 valign=3D"top" bgcolor=3D"#ffffff"><img src=3D"http://www.furnituretrai=
ningcompany.com/images/email/highpoint_2009_04/spacer_disclaimer_left.jp=
g" alt=3D"" /></td>=0D=0A<td valign=3D"top" bgcolor=3D"#ffffff"><img src=
=3D"http://www.furnituretrainingcompany.com/images/email/highpoint_2009_=
04/spacer_disclaimer_middle.jpg" alt=3D"" /><br /> <span style=3D"font-s=
ize: xx-small; font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #=
666666;"><big><big><big><big><small><small><small>If you are not attendi=
ng the High Point market in April but would still like to receive a free=
 Road Map to Sales Success poster visit us on the web at <span style=3D"=
text-decoration: underline;"><a class=3D"moz-txt-link-abbreviated" href=
=3D"http://www.furnituretrainingcompany.com">www.furnituretrainingcompan=
y.com</a></span>, or to speak with a Furniture Training Company represen=
tative, call toll free (866) 755-5996. We do not offer free shipping out=
side of the U.S. and Canada. Retailers outside of the U.S. and Canada ma=
y call for more information. Limit one free Road Map to Sales Success pe=
r company. Other copies of the poster may be purchased on our web site.<=
br /> <br /> </small></small></small></big></big></big></big></span> <sp=
an style=3D"color: #666666;"><small><span style=3D"font-size: xx-small;=
 font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><big><big><big><small=
><small>We hope you found this message to be useful. However, if you'd r=
ather not receive future emails of this sort from The Furniture Training=
 Company, please <a href=3D"http://www.furnituretraining.com/contact">cl=
ick here to unsubscribe</a>.<br /> <br /> </small></small></big></big></=
big></span></small><small><span style=3D"font-size: xx-small; font-famil=
y: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><big><big><big><small><small>&co=
py;Copyright 2009 The Furniture Training Company.<br /> 1770 North Resea=
rch Park Way, <br /> North Logan, UT 84341. <br /> All Rights Reserved.<=
/small></small></big></big></big></span></small></span><br /></td>=0D=0A=

<td valign=3D"top" bgcolor=3D"#ffffff"><img src=3D"http://www.furnituret=
rainingcompany.com/images/email/highpoint_2009_04/spacer_disclaimer_righ=
t.jpg" alt=3D"" /></td>=0D=0A</tr>=0D=0A</tbody>=0D=0A</table>=0D=0A<tab=
le border=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" width=3D"600" align=
=3D"center">=0D=0A<tbody>=0D=0A<tr>=0D=0A<td valign=3D"top" bgcolor=3D"#=
ffffff"><img src=3D"http://www.furnituretrainingcompany.com/images/email=
/highpoint_2009_04/footer.jpg" alt=3D"" /></td>=0D=0A</tr>=0D=0A</tbody>=
=0D=0A</table>=0D=0A<p><br /></p><br><hr><a href=3D'http://localhost/ftc=
/app/unsubscribe.php?action=3DoptOut&pid=3D6121&cid=3D19&email=3Dmarkl@f=
urnituretrainingcompany.com'>Click to Unsubscribe</a>
```

Comment: What platform/programming language/library/mail server/additional filters are you using? This seems like relevant information to me.

Comment: I don't get the problem, the "content that gets send" part looks correct. Where is the problem? Also, you might want to share the code you wrote to create the email.

Comment: Your example looks correct (all links absolute)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, even though when I copied and pasted the content into the application the necessary DOCTYPE, html, and body tags were in place, TinyMCE was stripping those tags. Which explains why the output only showed the content within the body tag.

I was able to fix the url rewrite problem by ensuring that the DOCTYPE, html and body tags were actually all in place.

And I fixed TinyMCE by adding in the fullpage plugin so that it no longer strips those tags from the input.

Answer (score 0):

There is a configuration option "convert_urls" which can be set to false to prevent URLs from being converted too.

Answer (score 0):

Since @Noah are sending expected content as email. Their is no problem with TinyMCE. 
Normally images are blocked by mail hosters. 
In my case, I was sending html content(with image) to gmail account. Google blockes images in mails.
Google display the following in every email

> Images are not displayed. Display images below - Always display
>   images from xxxx@xxxx.com

Just click on appropriate link to display images.

Thank You,
Aashish